# Copy the selected cells to new worksheet and show where it came from

Tags: excel

I copy a cell and paste the shortcut from worksheet A to worksheet B.  Now, I want to add a cell on worksheet B and show where it came from.  How can I do?  Thx!

Leo

Comment: If you select your cell on Sheet B and use the `Trace Precedents` tool, this will draw an arrow on the sheet which can be clicked to see where the data comes from.

Comment: VBA will doin this ..

Answer (score 0):

Trace precedents would show an arrow indicating a sheet. But it does not show the cell reference or the sheet name. 
One way of getting the Sheet and cell reference is to write an = sign in the cell below the copied cell and go to the cell on the sheet from which it was copied and press Enter. The text in the cell comes to the destination cell with formula underlying like Sheet1!C4. Now go to Tools menu and click on options. Under tab View check the formula check box and click OK to dismiss the option window. Now the formula is displayed with = sign. Just delete the = sign and go to Options and clear the check on the formula. The cell reference is now displayed.